# Creating a Trigger on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers

This is being done on Oracle 11, and I'm trying to create a trigger where if the incoming meets certain values, to update another table.

```
--CREATE TRIGGER ON ITX
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_I_LAST_RECEIVED
  AFTER INSERT ON ITEM_TRANSACTION_LOG
    FOR EACH ROW
      WHEN (
        NEW.ITEM_CONDITION_ID =  5005                                               -- REPAIRED
        AND NEW.WORKCENTER_ID IN (5001,5006,5063,5000,5022,5062)   -- EWRC
        AND NEW.ORDER_ITEM_OPER_ID = 5009                                      -- Perform Exit Routing
      )
BEGIN
  UPDATE PART 
  SET LAST_REPAIRED = SYSDATE
  WHERE PART_NO = :NEW.ITEM_PART_NO
END;
```

When I do, it adds it, but I get this (ORA-24344):

[image: oracle error screen]

Now, I understand SQL fairly well (T-SQL) and maybe I'm missing something - can someone eyeball this and tell me why it's not valid?

**EDIT**: 
The issue was missing semi-colon at the end of the update statement.   Oracle's semi-colon discrepencies drive me bonkers sometimes.

Here's the correct statement, and thanks to Justin Cave for finding it:

```
--CREATE TRIGGER ON ITX
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_I_LAST_RECEIVED
  AFTER INSERT ON ITEM_TRANSACTION_LOG
    FOR EACH ROW
      WHEN (
        NEW.ITEM_CONDITION_ID =  5005                                               -- REPAIRED
        AND NEW.WORKCENTER_ID IN (5001,5006,5063,5000,5022,5062)   -- EWRC
        AND NEW.ORDER_ITEM_OPER_ID = 5009                                      -- Perform Exit Routing
      )
BEGIN
  UPDATE PART 
  SET LAST_REPAIRED = SYSDATE
  WHERE PART_NO = :NEW.ITEM_PART_NO;    --add that semicolon!
END;
```

Comment: What does `show error` (assuming you're using SQL*Plus) show you is the actual compilation error?  Nothing jumps out at me.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on the train for home right now. I can give it a look when i get home and can VPN in.

Comment: On second pass, you are missing the semicolon at the end of your `update` statement.  There may be other compilation errors as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that when I get home.  If you submit that as an answer, and it's the problem, I'll mark yours as the correct answer

Comment: If that's what `show errors` shows the error to be, I'll post it as an answer.  I don't like posting that as an answer without seeing the actual error because it's entirely possible that the compiler is finding an error that I'm not.

Comment: Justin -- it was the semi-colon at the end of the update statement.  Adding that, allowed it to go in just fine.   Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update` statement is missing a semicolon at the end.  Since it sounds like you come from a T-SQL background, in SQL Server, semicolons are generally optional.  They're always required in Oracle

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE PART 
  SET LAST_REPAIRED = SYSDATE
  WHERE PART_NO = :NEW.ITEM_PART_NO;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but seems that you have to specify refenrece to `:NEW`
It should look like:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_I_LAST_RECEIVED
      AFTER INSERT ON ITEM_TRANSACTION_LOG
        REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
        FOR EACH ROW...
```

In current case reference to `OLD` will be empty record because of current trigger type. If it would be an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger then reference to `OLD`would be the value of the table record before update operation.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have missed the ":" before "NEW.ITEM_CONDITION_ID" and others columns, and ofcourse as "Justin Cave" mentioned you need ";" after update statement.